# Rotate a VIewController to landscape or portrait orientation in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

In my project changing the orientation for single view controller alone to both 
  *landscape and portrait.*

Here is the code i tried for changing orientation for view controller

@IBOutlet weak var imagePhoto: UIImageView!

Added in `viewDidLoad`:

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
  #selector(viewWillTransition(to:with:)), name: 
  NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)


  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: 
  UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
     if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
           appDelegate.orientationLock = .landscape

    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait


     }
   }
```

Code added in Appdelegatedata

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
   supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> 
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask {



    if let rootViewController = UIApplication.topViewController() {

        if rootViewController is PostImageZoomViewController {

            let controller = rootViewController as! 
     PostImageZoomViewController

            if controller.isPresented {

                return .all

            }

        }


    }



    return .portrait

}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say, you want to forcibly change the orientation of a particular viewController?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. yes @RakshithNandish